# how to check if the user chose the correct answer or not [React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am totally new to react native, so if this is a dumb question to ask  I apologize.

What I am trying to do is very simple but I can't get my head around it lol.

I have a multiple choice quiz app, the user have four options to choice from and simply when they chose the correct answer I want to change the background color of that button to
'green' to indicate the answer is correct and similarly when they chose the wrong answer change the background to "red" and to "green" the correct answer.

to keep it simple,  currently I only have 5 questions but i'll add more once I figure this out and the question number are randomly generated.

and here is my question, how do I check if the user chose the correct answer or not and change the background. I only want to check the answer once a button has been pressed. Currently my code checks the answer before you select an answer. I tried uesEffect to wait till the user choose an answer and check but it doesn’t seem to work.

any help would be appreciated, thank you in advanced.

```
const PracticeScreen = (props) => {
  const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState();
  const [userAnswer, setUseranswer] = useState();
  const [usedQuestionNumber] = useState([]);

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  
  if (usedQuestionNumber.length === 0) {
    setQuestionNumber(random);
    usedQuestionNumber.push(random);
  }

  function nextButtonHandler() {
    while (
      usedQuestionNumber.indexOf(random) !== -1 &&
      usedQuestionNumber.length !== 5
    ) {
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    }
    if (usedQuestionNumber.length === 5) {
      //display  score
      console.log("You have answered all the questions");
    } else {
      setQuestionNumber(random);
      usedQuestionNumber.push(random);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userAnswer === Answer[questionNumber].answer) {
      //change background color to green
      console.log("Yayyyy you got it right..!");
    } else {
      console.log(
       //change background color to red and to green the correct answer
        "Nope that's incorrect, the answer was :" +
          Answer[questionNumber].answer
      );
    }
    return () => {
      setUseranswer("");
    };
  }, [userAnswer]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Card style={styles.questionCard}>
        <Text>{Question[questionNumber].Q}</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card
        style={styles.choiceCard}
        onPress={() => setUseranswer(Question[questionNumber].A)}
      >
        <Text>{Question[questionNumber].A}</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card
        style={styles.choiceCard}
        onPress={() => setUseranswer(Question[questionNumber].B)}
      >
        <Text>{Question[questionNumber].B}</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card
        style={styles.choiceCard}
        onPress={() => setUseranswer(Question[questionNumber].C)}
      >
        <Text>{Question[questionNumber].C}</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card
        style={styles.choiceCard}
        onPress={() => setUseranswer(Question[questionNumber].D)}
      >
        <Text>{Question[questionNumber].D}</Text>
      </Card>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Card
          style={styles.cancelButton}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("cancel clicked");
          }}
        >
          <AntDesign name="close" size={60} color="white" />
        </Card>
        <Card style={styles.nextButton} onPress={nextButtonHandler}>
          <Entypo name="arrow-bold-right" size={60} color="white" />
        </Card>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You cannot push items to an array that is in the state
You need to put in a new set

Answer (score 0):

You might use `Animated` with `interpolate`

```
// create ref with Animated.value 0 
const animatedGreen = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

// function to be triggered on button click
const handlePress = () => Animated.timing(
                                animatedGreen,
                                { toValue: 150, duration: 1000 } 
                              ).start()
                                         

// usage
<Animated.View style={{ backgroundColor: animatedGreen.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 150], outputRange: ['rgb(0,0,0)', 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'] }) }} />
```

I created only the green animation, but you can do the same for red either manipulate all at same `ref` holds array (but it might get tricky for controlling different colors with different behaviors in case of a correct or a wrong answer)